# Excel: How to leave cell empty (instead of 0) when VLOOKUP has no match?

Tags: excel

I have an excel workbook with 2 worksheet: countries and companies. The companies worksheet is partially filled-in through `VLOOKUP`s in the countries worksheet, as follows:

countries:

```
     A       B
1 COUNTRY HOF_LTO
2 Belgium    4
3 Japan      5
4 Spain
5 Sweden     0
```

companies:

```
    A         B       C
1 COMPANY  COUNTRY HOF_LTO
2 Belgacom Belgium    4
3 Onkyo    Japan      5
4 Sony     Japan      5
5 ATTM     Spain      0
6 Nokia    Sweden     0
```

I'm filling the `C` column by using the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($B2;countries!$A$1:$C$5;MATCH(companies!B$1;countries!$1:$1;0);FALSE)
```

What goes wrong is: even though `Spain` does not have a `HOF_LTO`-value in countries, the formula puts `0` as the appropriate value in cell `companies!C5`. Instead it should leave the cell empty and only put in a zero (`0`) when it says `0` in the countries tab, as it does in the case of Sweden.

How do I need to edit the formula so it will leave cells empty when there is no country value to match?

Comment: You can use `IF()` you'll have to use your current formula twice (one in the comparison and once in the true (or false) then set the other to "" eg: `=IF(VLOOKUP=0,"",VLOOKUP)` (missed part of your question, re-reading now :D)

Comment: I thought of that but my Excel is slow as it is because of the (tens of thousands of) VLOOKUP's as it is. I was hoping for a less resource intensive solution :-)

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't doing this with a proper database application? If you have many tens of thousands of records you are probably looking at this problem like it's a nail because you are holding a hammer. What you actually need is a screwdriver (i.e. SQL Server, MS Access etc.)

Comment: Does your data change frequently? If not, you could use VBA to set static values instead of having a vlookup

Comment: The dataset only has to be calculated once. I then import the values into SPSS to do some statistical analysis. This will be a one-time excercise. I got a basic dataset from my university, which I have been expanding over time. In hindsight, I should have exported the original dataset to MySQL and go from there. It's just one of those things that grew into a beast and you didn't really notice. Now I almost have my dataset complete, I don't want to put in the effort to export it into a database first but I get your point :-)

Comment: Export into a data base? Use access you can copy paste, then simply create a query for the info. It would take minutes if that.

Comment: For the first one which should be an answer, these  comments are useless - There are very specific reasons people ask for this information, and suggesting other tools does not help.  Glad the OP was accomodating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If in your country sheet all countries are only present once you could use the following in stead:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(OFFSET(countries!$B$1;MATCH(B2;countries!A:A;0)-1;0));
    OFFSET(countries!$B$1;MATCH(B2;countries!A:A;0)-1;0);
    "")
```

Comment: there was an error in my first try, please see this corrected version!

Comment: If this works, then why have I been using VLOOKUP all this time? (actual question!)

Comment: You have been using vlookup because usually looking up stuff doesnt require the distinction you need this time! Glad to have been of help

Comment: no problem, I was just wondering if anything was still not functioning. Good luck!

Comment: It really is too bad there is no way to solve this without repeating the original formula twice. This is just too prone to errors when you have to change the formula.

Answer (score 46):

This should solve it:

```
=VLOOKUP(...) & ""
```

> This will force Excel into making that cell reference a text value,
>   thus preventing the conversion of blanks into zeroes.

*Taken from https://superuser.com/a/906954/222835*

Comment: Simple and effective. Many thanks for sharing this answer.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a hundred times more, so simple and the other solutions are really messy

Comment: Just as a warning, this will convert numbers to text strings which can have a number of unexpected consequences.

Comment: Brilliant method indeed

Answer (score 8):

```
=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP($B2;countries!$A$1:$C$5;MATCH(companies!B$1;countries!$1:$1;0);FALSE))
```

Concatenate ensures the data is treated like a string instead of a number.  If the value is just an empty cell, you'll simply get an empty cell.

Comment: Yeah, I like this a lot.  Thanks!

Comment: At least for suitable formats, this seems far superior to the accepted answer. It works for numbers too, as actual 0s in the source are still rendered as 0s - although the entire column does come out as text, which might b0rk certain formulae (though not mine in this case).

Comment: you can do :

    =""&VLOOKUP($B2;countries!$A$1:$C$5

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation on the `VLOOKUP` + concatenation answer which ensures that numeric values do not get converted to strings:

```
=IF(LEN(VLOOKUP(args) & "")=0,"",VLOOKUP(args))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if it is just the **presentation** of the data that you need to control, adjust the cell formatting to display 0 values as blank instead of as the digit zero.

Comment: It looks like some Countries are supposed to be 0 as in the case with `Sweden`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: Do a find and replace on the full array of your countries source workbook, replacing empty cells with @. (make sure "Find entire cells only" is checked when you do the Replace All.) Then go back and run your vlookups. Copy and paste values to get rid of the vlookups and only keep the results. Now search and replace @ symbols with nothing in the destination file. Voilà.

Comment: Not sure why anyone would downvote this.  This is by far the best solution because it retains numeric format ability instead of converting to string.  Though, I use a dash instead of @ symbol... as dash often means no value.

Answer (score 0):

The *cleanest* way I've found for text (pun intended), is to use the `CLEAN` function. :)

**Note**: This should only be used for columns where you are returning actual text. You can just omit this wrapper if you are returning numbers, dates, etc.

Simply wrap your [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) with the [`CLEAN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/clean-function-26f3d7c5-475f-4a9c-90e5-4b8ba987ba41) function like so:

`=CLEAN(VLOOKUP($B2,countries!$A$1:$C$5,MATCH(companies!B$1,countries!$1:$1,0),FALSE))`

Even better, wrap it all in an [`IFERROR`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) to make sure you don't get `#N/A` or the dreaded `#REF!`, etc. back; like so:

`=IFERROR(CLEAN(VLOOKUP($B2,countries!$A$1:$C$5,MATCH(companies!B$1,countries!$1:$1,0),FALSE)),"")`

**Bonus**: FIXED! All your formulas were incorrectly using semicolons instead of commas between the function arguments, and I'm rather surprised nobody caught that. >.<

**Generic**:

`=IFERROR(CLEAN(VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num,FALSE)),"")` - For Text
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num,FALSE),"")` - For Values
`=IFERROR(VALUE(VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num,FALSE)),"")` - For Values Forced

Comment: This is misleading, but it works for the same reason the other answers do - it converts the result to a string.

Comment: Misleading how? 

Comment: I was kinda terse, admittedly - Misleading in that 'clean' removes special characters, etc.  0 is not a special character, and blank is not a special character, and there are no special characters in the OP.  But it works, because it converts it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use(*) a UDF (user defined function) **`vlookup2`** that simplifies the typical `vlookup` usage a lot (and honors good performance and more readable formulas).

So the usage would be in the given example:

```vb
=VLOOKUP2(
   $B2  ;  countries!$A$1:$C$5  ;  MATCH( companies!B$1 ; countries!$1:$1 ; 0 )  ;  "" )
```

instead of e.g. (based on the nice [Pillowcase example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38679010/1915920)):

```vb
=VLOOKUP( 
   $B2  ;  countries!$A$1:$C$5  ;  MATCH( companies!B$1 ; countries!$1:$1 ; 0 ) ; FALSE) 
   & ""
```

in other cases (where e.g. the search criteria `$B2` may already be `#NV` or similar the following could make sense:

```vb
=VLOOKUP2(
   $B2  ;  countries!$A$1:$C$5  ;  MATCH( companies!B$1 ; countries!$1:$1 ; 0 ) ; "" ; "")
```

The code for `vlookup2` would be:

```vb
'simpler to use than vlookup
'only exact matches and 0 subst value support
'https://stackoverflow.com/a/55743343/1915920
'
Function vlookup2( _
  ByRef searchCriteria As Variant, _
  ByRef matrix As Variant, _
  ByRef columnIndex As Variant, _
  Optional zeroSubst As Variant, _
  Optional errSubst As Variant )

    Dim val As Variant:  val = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
                                 searchCriteria,  matrix,  columnIndex,  False )

    If Not IsMissing(errSubst) Then On Error GoTo EH  'EH = error handler
    If Not IsMissing(zeroSubst) And val = 0 Then val = zeroSubst

    vlookup2 = val
    Exit Function

EH:
    vlookup2 = errSubst        
End Function
```

---

(*): if you don't know something about it, it is as simple as this:

1. push *CTRL + F11* => `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications` window opens
2. insert a new module and paste the above code in the right editor
   [image]
3. close just opened window

---

For the german version one could add another one:

```vb
'https://stackoverflow.com/a/55743343/1915920
Function SVerweis2( _
    ByRef Suchkriterium As Variant, _
    ByRef Matrix As Variant, _
    ByRef SpaltenIndex As Variant, _
    Optional NullZahlSubst As Variant, _
    Optional FehlerSubst As Variant)

    SVerweis2 = vlookup2( Suchkriterium, Matrix, SpaltenIndex , NullZahlSubst, FehlerSubst )
End Function`
```